# Missing database connection error in PHP app

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, cakephp

I'm running a php app using Postgresql, and WAPP to run my servers. Currently running an Apache web server and a postgres server. I'm getting the following error:

> Missing Database Connection Error: A Database connection using "Postgres" was missing or unable 
>   to connect.    The database server
>   returned this error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password
>   supplied
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\missing_connection.ctp

I'm a bit of a newb, so I'm wondering - is it possible I placed my sql file in the wrong location? It's currently in the htdocs/databases folder (from where I'm running my app).

Does anyone know how to solve this? do I have to update a fixture somewhere, or supply a password somewhere? Or is the database simply not connected for some reason?

Thanks all!

Comment: "**no password supplied**"

Comment: Where would I go to set one up to access the database?

Comment: where you connect to it

Answer (score 0):

For test and development servers, you can tell postgres to skip password
checking altogether.

You can do it by editing `C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.30-0\postgresql\data\pg_hba.conf`

Simply replace all occurrences of `md5` to `trust`. Save file. And use the
Bitnami graphical console to restart the postgres server.